# Expanding the use of PlaceHolderMain in Sharepoint 2010?

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I want to create a 2 column layout in my master template page. I  want both the left and right HTML column < div >'s in my design to have wysiwyg editors. This is what I am picturing...

```
<div id="container">
<div class="left-side">

<div id="sub-menu">asp:menu</div>

<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderMain1" runat="server" />
</div>

<div class="right-side">
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderMain2" runat="server" />
</div>
</div>
```

but obviously, PlaceHolderMain1 or PlaceHolderMain2 are not optional content placeholders to select by default...

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-designer-help/working-with-content-placeholder-controls-HA102265026.aspx

Is there a way to create an additional HTML-PlaceHolder with SharePoint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By creating content types for a content page layout 
**[configure SharePoint's site settings -> then view content types under 'Site Objects' in SharePoint Designer]**, you could then take advantage of your "toolbox" located in SharePoint Designer.

```
Create your types and your page layout under site settings from your browser

Also assign your page layout to a specific master template 

Open up your new page layout in SharePoint Designer 

Then use the toolbox to drag any of the available content fields into your content page layout.

Save your layout page, check it in as major.  Done.
```

As a result, I was able to drag on a Rich HTML field PLUS a web zone, into each floating div in my content page layout.  FYI, you may or may not need to add on additional Tagprefix's to your content page layout, for example, if you are calling the asp:menu into it, be ready for that...

The solution also keeps you from re-creating multiple master templates, just because you need a new HTML layout scheme to choose from.